# What is a good/healthy mysql query execution time?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

What is a good/healthy mysql query execution time?

To my calculations:

> The site gets 1000 unique visitors per hr
>
> 10 page view for each unique visitor
>
> 5 minutes for each unique visitor (I'm ignoring this. I should,
>   right?)
>
> 1000*10=10000/(60*60) = 2.7 views per second.
>
> I have 3 queries on every page. 2.7*3 = 8.1 queries per second
>
> 1 second/8.1 = 0.123

So average query execution time must be less than 0.123.

Assuming visits don't increase, can we say anything less than 0.123 works for a healthy database?

Edit: I learned that this model would describe a server at 100% capacity but I should aim for 25-50% capacity. I'm a newbie and I don't know how to continue on this.

Comment: If the users are spending 5 minutes to read 10 pages, then they're not viewing a new page every few seconds. So, you're only going to get .27 initial page requests every second, or about 20 per minute. Those users then request a new page every 30 seconds (5 min / 10 pages), which means in aggregate it's around 22 requests per minute. 3 requests per page, is 66 hits per minute, which is about 1 second per query. If you database can't do that, you're hosed. At 25-50% capacity, that's 2-4 seconds per query. If it can't do THAT, you need to upgrade from your Pentium 2 processor.

Comment: It's just an example. How did you come up with ".27 initial page requests every second" ?

Comment: Your initial calculation of 2.7 requests per second dividing out the erroneous 10 requests gives .27. 1000=10000/(60*60) = .27 views per second.

Comment: That 10 belongs there if every person does 10 requests all at once.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your calculations are on the right path for determining the load on your server.  However, it misses the fact that a database server can handle multiple queries at the same time.

This is the difference between "bandwidth" and "latency".  "Bandwidth" is the number of queries that can be processed during a period of time.  "Latency" is the amount of time it take to get results back from one query.

In general, when you are looking at returning values for users, you want the *database* portion of the queries to finish in less than a couple hundred milliseconds (and probably within tens of milliseconds).  This allows the other components of the UI -- particularly the network, but also application-side logic -- to return within a second or two.  That is usually a reasonable response time for many applications.  You should choose an appropriate value -- 50 msec, 100 msec, 200 msec -- for your application and then design the database and hardware to achieve that goal.

You accomplish such times through several strategies, particularly focusing on indexes to speed database searches and on keeping commonly used data in memory.

Answer (score 1):

It is difficult to make accurate predictions:

- queries have different complexity
- part of execution time is overhead that doesn't hit the database engine
- parallel queries must be sequenced to common hardware
- performance is highly dependent on indexes and caches.

I'd focus on the application first, and when I find performance to be lacking, optimize. A few ideas, in order of growing desperation:

- if the application performs further reductions on returned data, move these into the database
- create indexes for the most common query types
- use a database engine that can use raw partitions, removing the file system layer
- move indexes to SSD
- store database tables on RAID1 (which you should be doing anyway)
- pre-calculate views